# Dynamically execute a stored procedure with reference cursor output

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a package like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_EXAMPLE
IS
  PROCEDURE SP_EXAMPLE_1 (inVal IN VARCHAR2, outCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
  PROCEDURE SP_EXAMPLE_2 (inVal IN VARCHAR2, outCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
  PROCEDURE SP_EXAMPLE_N (inVal IN VARCHAR2, outCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
  PROCEDURE SP_NON_CURSOR_EXAMPLE (inVal IN VARCHAR2, outVal OUT VARCHAR2);
END PKG_EXAMPLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_EXAMPLE
AS
  --for brevity, only showing one relevant procedure
  PROCEDURE SP_EXAMPLE_N (inVal IN VARCHAR2, outCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN outCur FOR SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE value = inVal;
  END SP_EXAMPLE_N;

END PKG_EXAMPLE;
```

At runtime I am looping through some records and I want to call procedures (only the ones with `outCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` cursor outputs) in this package dynamically. For *demonstration* purposes, I included `SP_NON_CURSOR_EXAMPLE` to show that I could call it like this:

```
DECLARE
  outVal  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN

  FOR rec IN (SELECT 'SP_NON_CURSOR_EXAMPLE' as spName, inData FROM table_name) LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CALL PKG_EXAMPLE.' || rec.spName || '(''' || rec.inData || ''', :myResult)'
    USING OUT outVal;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

This works. But how can I do this for the procedures that have `outCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` cursor outputs? I don't actually need the cursor results or care what they are, I just want to know whether the cursor returned > 0 results. I want something like this:

```
DECLARE
  crs  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  cnt  NUMBER;
BEGIN

  FOR rec IN (SELECT spName, inData FROM table_name) LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CALL PKG_EXAMPLE.' || rec.spName|| '(''' || rec.inData|| ''', :myResult)'
    USING OUT crs;

    cnt := crs%ROWCOUNT; -- this is what I need

  END LOOP;

END;
```

But the `%ROWCOUNT` is always zero. I believe that I have to `FETCH` the cursor before I can check whether it returned results, but I don't know what columns or types the cursor will return so I'm not sure what I can fetch into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be the best approach, but I found a working solution...

```
DECLARE
  crs    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  crsID  NUMBER;
  cnt    NUMBER  :=  0;
BEGIN

  FOR rec IN (SELECT spName, inData FROM table_name) LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CALL PKG_EXAMPLE.' || rec.spName|| '(''' || rec.inData|| ''', :myResult)'
    USING OUT crs;

    crsID:= DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(crs);
    cnt := 0;

    WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(crsID) > 0 
    LOOP
      cnt := cnt + 1;
    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;

END;
```